# Accessing private members via reference accessor

Tags: c++

What is the appropriate way to access private members of a referenced class instance? For example, accessing the `initialNumberOfColumns` from an instance of `Cookie`? Then have that value be used in another classes member function, such at `Game::Game()` after the reference accessor has retrieved the member of the `Cookie` class.

first.h:

```
class Cookie {
    public:
        Cookie();
        ~Cookie();
        void takeABite (int column, int row);
        int getNumberOfRows();
        int getNumberOfRows(int colNum);
        int getNumberOfColumns();
        int getNumberOfColumns(int rowNum);
        void display (std::ostream& output);

    private:
        int initialNumberOfRows;
        int numberOfRows;
        int numberOfColumns
        int* cookie;
};
```

second.h:

```
class Game {
    public:
        Game();
        bool gameEnded();
        bool biteIsLegal (int column, int row);
        Cookie& getCookie();

    private:
        Cookie cookie;
};
```

second.cpp is where I am having difficult. I know I need to use `Cookie& Game::getCookie()` but I am not sure how to return the private members of the `Cookie` class such that they can be accessed in the member function `Game()` below.:

```
Cookie& Game::getCookie() {
    return //not sure how to access;
}

Game::Game() {
    initialNumberOfRows = numberOfRows = 4 + rand() % (MAXROWS - 4);
    numberOfColumns = numberOfRows;

    while (numberOfColumns == numberOfRows) {
        numberOfColumns = 4 + rand() % (MAXROWS - 4);
    }

    cout << "The cookie has " << numberOfRows << " rows of " 
         << numberOfColumns << " columns" << endl;

    for (int row = 0; row < numberOfRows; ++row) {
        cookie[row] = numberOfColumns;
    }
}
```

Comment: If it was not a private member but a public one, do you know how to do that? Good news, returning a reference to a private class member works exactly the same way.

Comment: I believe so. I would put `return cookie` right? But that just gives me the private member `Cookie cookie` of the class `Game`. How do I access the `cookie.initialNumberOfRows`?

Comment: @JohnnyMopp: except it does not appear that `Cookie` has a getter for `initialNumberOfRows`.

Comment: You did not ask about accessing some member of cookie. `getCookie()` returns a reference to a `Cookie` class instance. You asked what its return statement should be. That's the answer. If that's not what you're asking, you need to edit your question, and make it clear exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Missed that....deleted

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I believe my edit to the beginning of the post now makes it clear what I am trying to do.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Yes, it is accessing `initialNumberOfRows` that is causing me trouble.

Comment: @pstatix When you say you want to access `initialNumberOfRows` do you mean you want to read it or do you also want the ability to modify it? And on a slightly unrelated note, what's `int* cookie;` supposed to be? <-- looks like you may have gotten a bit confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Game` class has a `cookie` member.  That is what the `Game::getCookie()` method should return:

```
Cookie& Game::getCookie() {
    return cookie;
}
```

Now, inside of the `Game` constructor, you have direct access to the `cookie` member, so you don't need to use `getCookie()` to access it.  And the `Cookie` class has public methods for **reading** most of the values you are trying to use, but it DOES NOT provide any access to **set** those member values, or any access to its **private** `initialNumberOfRows` member at all.

The things you are trying to do in the `Game` constructor should be done in the `Cookie` constructor instead:

```
Cookie::Cookie() {
    initialNumberOfRows = numberOfRows = 4 + rand() % (MAXROWS - 4);

    numberOfColumns = numberOfRows;
    while (numberOfColumns == numberOfRows) {
        numberOfColumns = 4 + rand() % (MAXROWS - 4);
    }

    cookie = new int[numberofRows];

    for (int row = 0; row < numberOfRows; ++row) {
        cookie[row] = numberOfColumns;
    }
}
```

Then the `Game` constructor can log the values as needed:

```
Game::Game() {
    cout << "The cookie has " << cookie.getNumberOfRows() << " rows of " 
         << cookie.getNumberOfColumns() << " columns" << endl;
}
```

Now, that being said, the `Cookie` class is violating the [Rule of Three](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)).  It needs to implement a **copy constructor** and **copy assignment operator** to ensure the integrity of its `int *cookie` field:

```
class Cookie {
public:
    Cookie();
    Cookie(const Cookie &src);
    ~Cookie();

    Cookie& operator=(const Cookie &rhs);
    void swap(Cookie &other);

    ...

private:
    int initialNumberOfRows;
    int numberOfRows;
    int numberOfColumns
    int* cookie;
};
```

```
#include <algorithm>

Cookie::Cookie() {
    initialNumberOfRows = numberOfRows = 4 + rand() % (MAXROWS - 4);

    numberOfColumns = numberOfRows;
    while (numberOfColumns == numberOfRows) {
        numberOfColumns = 4 + rand() % (MAXROWS - 4);
    }

    cookie = new int[numberOfRows];
    std::fill(cookie, cookie + numberOfRows, numberOfColumns);
}

Cookie::Cookie(const Cookie &src) :
    initialNumberOfRows(src.initialNumberOfRows),
    numberOfRows(src.numberOfRows),
    numberOfColumns(src.numberOfColumns),
    cookie(new int[numberOfRows])
{
    std::copy(src.cookie, src.cookie + numberOfRows, cookie);
}

Cookie::~Cookie()
{
    delete[] cookie;
}

Cookie& Cookie::operator=(const Cookie &rhs)
{
    if (this != &rhs)
        Cookie(rhs).swap(*this);
    return *this;
}

void Cookie::swap(Cookie &other)
{
    std::swap(initialNumberOfRows, other.initialNumberOfRows);
    std::swap(numberOfRows, other.numberOfRows);
    std::swap(numberOfColumns, other.numberOfColumns);
    std::swap(cookie, other.cookie);
}
```

Otherwise, change the `int *cookie` member to a `std::vector` instead, and let the compiler and STL handle the hard work of memory management for you:

```
#include <vector>

class Cookie {
public:
    Cookie();

    ...

private:
    int initialNumberOfRows;
    int numberOfRows;
    int numberOfColumns
    std::vector<int> cookie;
};
```

```
Cookie::Cookie() {
    initialNumberOfRows = numberOfRows = 4 + rand() % (MAXROWS - 4);

    numberOfColumns = numberOfRows;
    while (numberOfColumns == numberOfRows) {
        numberOfColumns = 4 + rand() % (MAXROWS - 4);
    }

    cookie.resize(numberOfRows);
    std::fill(cookie.begin(), cookie.end(), numberOfColumns);
}
```

Comment: The second.cpp initially had: `int initialNumberOfRows`, `int numberOfRows`, `int numberOfColumns` & `int cookie[MAXROWS]`. I'm supposed to remove them since they are defined in the first.h and second.h; but when removed, they are hence undefined and I need to redefine them. By `return cookie` I have access to the member, but I need to have the defined somehow.